# Binding to and traversing through content delivered via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not sure how to bind to content loaded via Ajax and traverse through it to see if any new elements have been added. Here is the code I have currently (jQuery):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(document).find('.my-selector').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();
        }
    });

});
```

I know this won't bind to future content loaded via Ajax, but I don't know exactly how to bind traversing. I've tried using `$(document).on('ajaxStop')` and then traversing, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I can't use `.on('click')` or any of the other usual events like that because the new content isn't loaded yet.

Any way to do this? The code above works great for content already on the page, so I just need it modified to where it will bind to future `.my-selector` elements as well.

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the issue. It stemmed from loading the content via Ajax through a callback function within the `fadeIn` method. Apparently jQuery won't traverse through DOM elements that are not yet fully visible. I simply changed the method from `fadeIn` to `show` and it works fine when binding to the `ajaxStop` event with `on()`. Here is the updated code for anyone wanted to know:

```
$(document).on('ajaxStop', function() {
    $(this).find('.my-selector').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to give us a larger code sample here Thomas. The code above has no ajax request in it so we have no way of knowing what you're loading or when. All you showed us above was a snippet of code that shows/hides elements on document load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me perfectly with `ajaxStop()` event.

Here's a working sample (with `console.log()`, so use a browser that will not choke on them):

http://jsfiddle.net/uyMJZ/

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code and it is working now. Apparently you cannot traverse through DOM elements that have not been fully loaded via fadeIn(). I was fading in the content, and I guess jQuery took it as the content not visible on the page. Once I change it to simply use .show() instead, I had no problems traversing, finding and manipulating the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Start reading the docs on the now-deprecated [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method, and learn how to implement it using `on()` instead.

Basically, with AJAX-loaded DOM elements, you need to use some kind of delegation. The simplest (but least efficient) way to do this is to bind to the `document` using `on()`:

```
$(document).on('click','.my-selector', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

A better way to do it is to delegate to the closest DOM container. For instance, if you were adding elements to a list, you could delegate your handler to the list itself:

```
$('ul#news').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    // stuff for whenever a li is clicked, old or new
});
```

Comment: I know how to use on(). :-) I do delegate to the closest selector that is always available from page load, but I was just using that make a point. The issue stemmed from the content not being fully loaded from a fadeIn callback.